# jquery post problem

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post

I have a form and when I click on submit it fires a script.

Part of the code is:

```
        if(hasError == false) {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#myForm").fadeOut("fast", function(){
            $("#myForm").before('<img src="../images/loading.gif" alt="Loading" id="loadingImage" />');
        });

        $.post("mail.php",
            { emailFrom: emailFromVal, emailName: nameVal, emailMessage: messageVal },
                function(data){
                    $("#loadingImage").fadeOut("fast", function() {                
                        $("#loadingImage").before('<p>Your message has been sent. Cheers!</p>');                                            
                    });
                }
             );
    }
```

When the form is submitted, the loading image displays ... and stays !!

If I use Firebug, while the loading image is displayed, and enter in the console:

```
$("#loadingImage").fadeOut("fast", function() {                
                        $("#loadingImage").before('<p>Your message has been sent. Cheers!</p>');
```

The image disappears and the text appears.

Why?

Thanks a lot

Note: the email is sent

Comment: The callback passed to `$.post()` is only executed if the request succeeds - does mail.php return a 200 OK?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your new element is added after all the DOM elements have been binded with jQuery methods. Dynamic elements need to be binded once they are loaded. Quickest solution is to add the HTML on the page so jQuery can bind the element when the page loads

```
<img src="../images/loading.gif" alt="Loading" id="loadingImage" style="display:none" />
```

Comment: Thanks guys.I've tired both solutions and it didn't help. I still have the loading image displayed ; and the email sent. Not sure how to use FireBug ... but it looks like there is no errors. Also, the POST mail.php returns a 200 OK. But nothing in the 'response' tab ...

Comment: For something to show up in the Response tab of FireBug, you have to send some text from the mail.php. Perhaps, "Messages Sent" at end of the script. Also, you might want to verify the code is being executed inside the callback by adding an alert before executing $("#loadingImage").fadeOut, ex: alert("after i click ok, the image should disappear");

Answer (score 1):

Your first fadeout is ending after the img is created. You should do:

```
if(hasError == false) {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#myForm").fadeOut("fast", function(){
            $("#myForm").before('<img src="../images/loading.gif" alt="Loading" id="loadingImage" />');
            $.post("mail.php", { emailFrom: emailFromVal, emailName: nameVal, emailMessage: messageVal },
                function(data){
                    $("#loadingImage").fadeOut("fast", function() {                
                        $("#loadingImage").before('<p>Your message has been sent. Cheers!</p>');                                            
                    });
                }
             );        
        });
}
```

As you can see, we moved the `$.post()` call into the first `fadeOut()` callback function.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Apologies guys. It works. I was trying with Google Chrome, and I'm sure that there is something wrong with the caching system ... I've applied both of your workaround together. 1- I've added an img tag within my page, and I've change the script as per Edgar advice (also, not sure it has any impact). Thanks a lot for your quick help on this.